# Create a row for each cell that has data from multiple columns

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, normalization, unpivot

I'm dealing with data that has been generated from a survey that has a unique respondant ID as the first column and then has multiple columns relating to the choices of country that the respondent was looking at in relation to finding employees. So my table looks something like:

```
RespondentID  Andorra  Austria  Belgium  Cyprus  Denmark  Finland  France   

2546078180    Andorra  NULL     NULL     Cyprus  NULL     NULL     NULL 
2546077668    NULL     NULL     Belgium  NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL 
2546077120    NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL    Denmark  Finland  NULL
```

What I want to end up with is a table that lists the Respondent ID for each answer given. So on the above data it would look like:

```
RespondentID  Country   

2546078180    Andorra
2546078180    Cyprus
2546077668    Belgium
2546077120    Denmark
2546077120    Finland
```

As this should allow me to create a table detailing the countries that a respondent is linked with and then I can join this table to the other responses which were mostly yes/no or single answers which we need to do reporting on the data.

This data is coming in via an Excel spreadsheet so it would also be acceptable to do some formatting prior to the import into SQL if this is required or better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`UNPIVOT`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to normalize your table:

```
SELECT u.RespondentID, u.Country
FROM @source
UNPIVOT (Country FOR c IN (Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Cyprus, Denmark, Finland, France)) u
```

`@source` is a table that contains the data imported from your Excel worksheet.

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @source TABLE
(
    RespondentID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Andorra VARCHAR(25),
    Austria VARCHAR(25),
    Belgium VARCHAR(25),
    Cyprus VARCHAR(25),
    Denmark VARCHAR(25),
    Finland VARCHAR(25),
    France VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO @source 
(RespondentID, Andorra,   Austria, Belgium,  Cyprus,   Denmark,    Finland,   France)
VALUES
(2546078180,   'Andorra', NULL,    NULL,     'Cyprus', NULL,       NULL,      NULL),
(2546077668,   NULL,      NULL,    'Belgium', NULL,    NULL,       NULL,      NULL),
(2546077120,   NULL,      NULL,    NULL,      NULL,    'Denkmark', 'Finland', NULL)

-- I assume that 'NULL' cell values from your Excel sheet become NULL during the import.
```

**Output:**

```
RespondentId         Country
-------------------- -------------------------
2546078180           Andorra
2546078180           Cyprus
2546077668           Belgium
2546077120           Denkmark
2546077120           Finland
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this solution as well. :)

Comment: This is also a very good solution, I've never used unpivot before so perhaps you can help me with a quick question? Some of the answers in the country columns of the original data vary in language, for example Germany can have Germany or Deutschland in it. Is there a way to convert anything that isn't a null in a column to be a specific value at the same time as running this?

Comment: @user3318535: Yes, this is easy: Instead of `SELECT`-ing the cell's value (`u.Country`), you can `SELECT` the cell's column name (`u.c`): `SELECT u.RespondentID, u.c …`. (Explanation: The `Country FOR c` part of the `UNPIVOT` clause essentially means that `c` receives the cell's column name--that's why it gets followed by an `IN (…)` enumeration of column names--, and `Country` receives the cell's value. Since your columns names are in a fixed language, you can simply select these instead of the cell values themselves.)

Comment: @user3318535: An alternative solution is to create an additional lookup table `lookup`, containing two columns `OriginalValue` and `TranslatedValue` and values such as `('Germany', 'DE'), ('Deutschland', 'DE'), ('Allemagne', 'DE'), ('France', 'FR'), 'Francia', 'FR'), …`. Then `JOIN` it to your unpivoted table `ON u.Country = lookup.OriginalValue`; finally, `SELECT …, lookup.TranslatedValue` instead of `u.Country`.

Comment: Genius, u.c does it for me though the look up table is a good shout as well. Changed to be the best answer. Thanks a million!

Comment: @user3318535: You are welcome. I've never used `UNPIVOT` before, either, but your question seemed like a great opportunity to see how it worked… so I learnt quite a lot, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

UNION clause is the way to go:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT RespondentID, Field1 as Country
    FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT RespondentID, Field2 as Country
    FROM myTable
    UNION
    ....
    UNION
    SELECT RespondentID, Fieldn as Country
    FROM myTable) t
  WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The result of this query will also contain rows for all the `NULL` cells.

Comment: Yay! Thank you, this was nice and simple and easily replicated on other tables. Maybe one last question, it turns out no one is hiring people in Andorra so in this particular case that column is always Null and I think this is returning a Null value for every respondentID:

RespondentID country
2500979822 NULL
2500979822 Deutschland
2501468008 NULL
2501468008 Deutschland
2501468008 Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika
2501486940 NULL
2501486940 Hungary

Is there a way of filtering out the Nulls at this stage?

Comment: that can be fixed with WHERE in a wrapper query

Comment: Updated the answer to exclude NULLs

Comment: I'm being thick, of course you can! :) I think I've just been staring at this data for too long!